# Using multiple .Where() calls or && conditions for LinqToEntities queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Are the following two queries equivalent?  If they are not equivalent, which performs better? Is there a way I can see the sql output of the queries?

```
var query1 = items.Where(i => i.Enabled == true).Where(i => i.Name == "Bob");

var query2 = items.Where(i => i.Enabled == true && i.Name == "Bob");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andrew says, the two options are equivalent. One practically useful difference is that you can easily generate conditions in the `Where` clause programmatically. For example if you wanted to exclude certain names:

```
var query = items;
for(string name in excluded) 
  query = query.Where(i => i.Name != excluded);
```

This is something that cannot be done easily when writing query using `&&` operator.

Comment: whats wrong with `query.where(i => !exluded.Contains(i.Name))`?

Comment: last i checked EF does not support contains.  Also it is just an example, very often you only want to use those filters that have a value, so it becomes if(foo!=null)(query=query.where(x=>x.foo==foo)

Comment: @Jamiec: If `Contains` is supported then it is certainly fine. However composing `Where` clauses is more general approach - you can use it to express more general conditions.

Comment: @Andrey, @Thomas: `Contains` is supported in EF 4, but not EF 1.

Answer (score 2):

Both queries will translate to the same SQL - you can use a tool like LinqPad to verify this if you want (I just did). The LINQ provider that translate your expression trees into T-SQL is smart enough to understand that these queries are synonymous.  Of course this means that both queries will perform equally as well.